# Property set to true, but it's still false - how is that possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basic ASP.NET 4.0 Website application (Website, not WebApplication).

I am trying to make **standard ASP.NET label control** visible.

I set Visible property = true. But it's still False, doesn't change.

Here is the debugger screenshot.

After debugger moved from line 40 to line 41, the label's Visible property is still False.

**How is that possible ???**

P.S. AFAIK, ASP.NET serves requests per thread, so when debugging it's still the same thread (same request, same thread) and I am the only one executing this app, locally.

[image]

Comment: it may take the view state time to churn.

Answer (score 0):

There are various options, depending on your code, e.g.

1. Property setter and getter do not have same data source, e.g.

`public bool Visible { set { ; } get { return this.visible; } }`

or

```
public bool Visible { set { SetRemotely(value); } get { return cachedValue; } }
```

or

```
public bool Visible
{
    set { if (someCondition) this.visible = value; }
    get { return this.visible; }
}
```

2. Multithreading - another thread has changed the property.
3. Optimizer - the commands were performed in another order due to optimization.

More information on the property, your threading pattern, build settings, could help narrow it down.

Comment: Danny, what are you talking about? :)
it's not a user control, it's a standard asp.net label control. 
Does the screenshot make any sense to you?

Comment: @monstro a. You could add the type of the object to your question. b. In most cases no, however, there are always edge cases. Perhaps the parent is set to visible = false.

Comment: a) Well, I assumed people answering know what ASP.NET WebForms Label control is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label(v=vs.110).aspx
b) Don't understand what you are trying to say man, you see the debugger yellow marker on a screenshot? That's the next debugger step after Visible is set to "true", look in the "Watch" window - is it "true" or "false"? Explain that :)

Comment: @monstro People know what it is, however, you can name any object by any name. lblImpersonation could be any class including other ASP.NET controls.

Comment: @monstro Without more context, it is impossible to tell the exact answer.

Comment: what do you mean, what is not clear?
Its ASP.NET 4 website. Nothing else.